# How can I remove the search button in Mobile Design?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How can I remove the search button in Mobile Design? As far as I know display: none code this should work but unfortunately I am not able to. I would be very happy if someone can help. Is it a typo error or is there something I've overlooked? I spent about two hours but couldn't figure it out. My codes are like this:

My React codes are like this:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import styles from './Hero.module.css'
    import {AiOutlineSearch} from 'react-icons/ai'
    
    function Hero() {
      return (
        <div className={styles.hero}>
          <form>
            <div className={styles.text}>
                <label>Where</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Search Location' />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.from}>
                <span className={styles.border}></span>
                <label>From</label>
                <input type="date" />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.until}>
            <span className={styles.border}></span>
                <label>Until</label>
                <input type="date" />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.search_btn}>
                <AiOutlineSearch />
                <button className={styles.btn}>Search for cars</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Hero
```

```
My CSS Modules Codes like this:
```

```css
    
    .hero {
        background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519641471654-76ce0107ad1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2342&q=80')
          no-repeat center/cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
      
        display: flex;
      }
      
      form {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        max-width: 700px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 10%;
        padding: 6px 15px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 0px 8px 24px;
        background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.9);
      }
      
      form label {
        font-size: 0.78rem;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
      }
      
      .text, .from, .until {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      
      form input {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        font-family: 'Epilogue', sans-serif;
      }
      
      form .text_input {
        width: 300px;
        font-size: 1rem;
      }
      
      form input:focus {
        outline: none;
      }
      
      .from, .until {
        border-left: 1px solid #333;
        padding-left: 6px;
      }
      
      form .search_btn {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
      
      .search_btn button {
        display: none;
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
        form {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          max-width: 100%;
          margin: auto 1rem;
        }
      
      
        .text, .from, .until {
          width: 100%;
          padding: .2rem;
        }
      
        .from, .until {
          border-left: none;
        }
      
        .text_input {
          font-size: 0.8rem;
        }
      
        
        .text_input{
          font-size: 0.8rem;
        }
      
        form label {
          padding: 0.4rem 0;
        }
      
        .border {
          border-top: 1px solid #333;
          padding: 8px;
      
        }
      
        .search_btn {
          width: 100%;
          border-top: 1px solid #333;
          padding: 8px 0;
        }
      
        .search_btn .btn {
          display: block;
          background-color: #593cfb;
          color: #fff;
          font-weight: 600;
          font-size: 1rem;
          border: none;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 12px 18px;
          margin: .5rem 0;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
      
        .search_btn .btn:hover {
          background-color: #4733b7;
          transition: background-color 1s;
        }
      
        .icon {
          display: none;
        }
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `className={style.icon}` in its icon `<AiOutlineSearch className={style.icon} />`

Comment: If I'm not making a mistake, your suggestion doesn't work. Can you explain a little more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the search icon which is an SVG through the div that is wrapping both the search icon and the button, this way:

```
.search_btn svg:nth-of-type(1) {
display: none;
```

}

This is basically saying, select the first SVG icon that the element with the .search_btn class has and display none.